# Weblogic could not find class in WEB-INF->classes directory

Tags: weblogic9.x

I have a very weird problem.That my web project deployed to the Weblogic 10.0,Monday afternoon,and every thing works fine.But the next day morning, i checked the application, it reported could not find class that i write myself below the  WEB-INF->classes directory.

I also use ant to build my project,But the same war file works on Weblogic10.3 and Tomcat5.5.So it may be the Weblogic 10.0's issue.But i also test it in another environment which have Weblogic 10.0, and it could not work too.

So could anyone can help with it ? I work a whole day yesterday to figure this out.
Even change the JDK to recompile the code and war file.

Please Help or leave something that helps, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally figure the issue out. That cause the jdk version matters. 
The annotation "@override" in jdk1.5 was not supported as in jdk1.6. 
And the Weblogic10.0 still use the jdk1.5, so it matters.